# link is getting truncated, any ideas why?

Tags: vb.net

I have been making some progress on this but still have some issues to resolve.

Hopefully, this one won't be that hard.

I have this:

```
For Each item In Request.QueryString("doc").Split(","c)
    sb.Append("http://default.html?k=")
    sb.Append(item)
    sb.Append("&p=2&o=m</p>")
Next
```

When I test this code:

```
Response.Write(sb.ToString())
```

I get:

```
http://default.html?k=122&p=2&o=m

http://default.html?k=123&p=2&o=m
```

That's exactly what we are looking for

When we assign it to a variable like:

```
Dim linkList As String = sb.ToString()
```

However, when I loop through linkList
and write it to the screen, it is spitting out only the letter h.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it if possible?

```
Dim link As String

For Each link I linkList

    'let me know if I am still getting the links
    response.write link

    'we will save all the links later
Next
```

As always, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: how can you loop through linkList when its a string? you would need an array or list (well something that implements IEnumerable), my guess its this what is causing it to spit out one letter at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not loop through a string and get another string (note: **linkList is a String** - `Dim linkList As String = sb.ToString()`). That's why you get the h it's trying to pick the Chars in the string. Place the strings in an array then loop through the array. Try this:

```
Dim linkArray() As String

For Each item In Request.QueryString("doc").Split(","c)
    Dim stb As New StringBuilder
    stb.Append("http://default.html?k=")
    stb.Append(item)
    stb.Append("&p=2&o=m</p>")
    linkArray.add(stb.toString())
Next

For Each link As String In linkArray
    response.write link
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not closing your `<a>` tag

```
&p=2&o=m</p>
```

Notice the `</p>` to close a paragraph without the closing `<a>` tag with `</a>`.

Try to *view source* and you'll probably see the HTML is malformed in that way.

Comment: Thanks @Eric; You guys at this forum are spectacular with responding and helping us out. When I said this, it is probably out of ignorance but the code is just supposed to spit out the url, I don't see where <a>...</a> is a part of the code. Besides, the problem begins inside the For each...Next. Up till that point, the entire link is rendering correctl

Comment: Do a *view source* in the final HTML output.  Past in the HTML generated in the problematic part of your page.  Be sure to format it as code when you post it.